# How to achieve dynamic filtering in Tableau based on relevant values in the data source?

Tags: database, data-visualization, tableau-api

So I currently am using Tableau 9.3 and **need help trying to achieve 'dynamic filtering'**

I have 3 filters set in the filters tab for my worksheet: Category, Country, Item.

The filter gives me a complete list of all values in the database but I know for a fact that some do not have values.

I.e. If I filter by Category A, my worksheet goes blank until a filter that has those values pops up.

**I want to only have a 'Custom Value List' of values that have those records for the sheet I am trying to filter instead of a massive long list of all possibilities.**

I have had no luck with custom value list maybe I am doing something wrong?

Please help and advise.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand this: *"If I filter by Category A, my worksheet goes blank until a filter that has those values pops up"* What do you mean "pops up"?

Comment: @Nicarus As in the database has a value for that filter the dashboard becomes populated again. So If Category A is blank -> dashboard goes blank. Change the filter to Category B -> Dashboard re-appears as there is data for that. But I want to exclude A and just show B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tableau 9.2.3 on-wards provides two options when you are filtering the data -

```
"Only relevant values" - Will give only relevant values which are present on sheet not all data set.
"All Context values" - context filters themselves can be set to show all values or only relevant values, in the latter case that would be only after other context filters are applied.
"All values in database"- Will include all the values in the data base.
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to filter options, and make sure "Only relevant values" is checked. If I understood your question correctly, this should work.